# Go: C like macros for writing test code

Tags: macros, go

When writing test code, I do a lot of this

```
if (!cond) {
    t.Fatal("error message")
}
```

It's a bit tedious. So I'd like to achieve the following

```
CHECK(cond, "error message")
```

So I attempted this

```
func CHECK(t *testing.T, cond bool, fmt string, a ...interface{}) {
  if !cond {
    t.Fatal(fmt, a)
  }
}
```

If it were a C macro it would've worked perfectly. But in Go, the line number where the failure is is wrong.

Is there a fix for this?

Comment: downvote make no sense.this is a valid question

Answer (score 1):

Sadly you can't do that.

A workaround would be to get the line / function yourself, something like the trace function from https://stackoverflow.com/a/25954534/145587.

Comment: hmm. That's a pity. I'd really like to do that. This make go feel too much like Java, which is bad. :)

Comment: @lang2 oh not even close, java is the devil followed closely by ruby.

Comment: I tried googling to see if anyone has written a decent 3rd party macro preprocessor for golang, but didn't find anything interesting. but maybe I missed something, it's worth sniffing around.

Comment: @Not_a_Golfer there's [go generate](http://golang.org/s/go1.4-generate) in Go 1.4  but IMO it's too much work for adding a debug statement.

Comment: @OneOfOne I know, but from how I read the spec, it's not for things like this, but for say generating protobuf code automatically, etc. What would be cool is a tool that wraps go build/run itself and does it automatically. There's a generics library that works that way.

Comment: @Not_a_Golfer ultimately `go generate` can be used for generics,that's more or less one of the goals for it, one can easily write a wrapper that calls go generate then go build / install.

Answer (score 1):

You could possibly make use of [`runtime.Callers()`](http://golang.org/pkg/runtime/#Callers)+[`runtime.Caller()`](http://golang.org/pkg/runtime/#Caller): the first one gives you the call stack while the second allows to extract the debug info about any arbitrary stack frame (obtained from that list).

Your `CHECK()` function is always one function call down the place the check should have happened at if it was a macro, so you can inspect the stack frame just above.

---

Update: the only functon which is really needed is `runtime.Caller()`.  Here's your case, simplified:

```
package main

import (
    "runtime"
    "testing"
)

func CHECK(t *testing.T, cond bool) {
    if !cond {
        _, fname, lineno, ok := runtime.Caller(1)
        if !ok {
            fname, lineno = "<UNKNOWN>", -1
        }
        t.Fatalf("FAIL: %s:%d", fname, lineno)
    }
}

func TestFoo(t *testing.T) {
    CHECK(t, 12 == 13)
}
```

When saved as `check_test.go` and run via `go test`, it produces:

```
$ go test
--- FAIL: TestFoo (0.00 seconds)
        check_test.go:14: FAIL: /home/kostix/devel/go/src/check/check_test.go:19
FAIL
exit status 1
FAIL    check   0.001s
```

where line 19 is the line a call to `CHECK()` is located inside `TestFoo()`.

Answer (score 0):

While the above answer to use CHECK() function will work, I think that the actual answer is code readibility. Much of Go has been designed as a compromise to increase readibility among the community as a whole. See gofmt for example. Most people will agree that it's format is not best for every case. But having a convention agreed to by all is a huge plus for Go. The same answer is to your question. Go is for writing code for your peers, not for yourself. So don't think "I prefer this." Think "what will people reading my code understand."

Your original code should be like this, without parenthesis.

```
if !cond {
    t.Fatal("error message")
}
```

This is idiomatic and every Go coder will recognize it instantly. That is the point.